# How can I make UITabbar background color clear?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I need to design a Tabbar Like This:
[image]

Well, For this design I am using a custom Class for getting the shape and arc with shadow. And For Centre button I am adding a button in the middle programmatically. Here is the class used for Tabbar shape:

```
@IBDesignable
class DesignerTab: UITabBar {

private var shapeLayer: CALayer?
private func addShape() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = createPath()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    
    //The below 4 lines are for shadow above the bar. you can skip them if you do not want a shadow
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:0)
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 10
    shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3

    if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
        self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
    } else {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    }
    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
}
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.isTranslucent = true
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.tintColor = .clear
    
    self.addShape()
}
func createPath() -> CGPath {
    let height: CGFloat = 27 
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let centerWidth = self.frame.width 
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) 
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - (height * 2)+10), y: 0))
    
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 25, y: height-0))

    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + (height * 2)-10), y: 0),
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 25, y: height-0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
    path.close()

    return path.cgPath
}
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return nil }
    for member in subviews.reversed() {
        let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
        guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else { continue }
        return result
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

The problem is that I want Centre button's background to be clear, There should not be any tabbar showing in background.Here is what I need :
[image]

and here is what I got :

[image]

We can clearly see there is white color shown in background. To resolve it I tried:

```
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
    
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .clear
    
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.tabBar.tintColor = .clear
```

but it didn't work for me. Anybody Plz tell me how can I get this tabbar background clear?
Thanks.

View Hierarchy in Debugger:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your view hierarchy in UI Debugger?

Comment: @Rj19 Have you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem...

Comment: @nirav i set viewcontroller bottom to view not to safeArea and added this: 
            let barAppearance = UIBarAppearance()
            barAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance(barAppearance: barAppearance)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance

Answer (score 0):

The white background is caused by the `backgroundImage` of the `tabBar`. We need to set it to an empty image to make the `tabBar` transparent. Additionally you might want to set `shadowImage` also empty, otherwise you would see a square border also

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

With these two changes and using the `ShapeLayer` you created, I could get the desired effect. Please refer below image
[image]

Comment: not working for me? is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: No these are the additional changes I have other than what you already have mentioned.  It seems your image does not overlap with the tab bar. So if the view, where images are added also has a white background, you might not see the difference. Could you try setting a different background color to the view, where images are added ?